# All possible collections of present giving permutations

Tags: c#, linq, permutation

So Christmas is coming up and every year my family pulls names from a hat for who should buy present for who, and invariably there are concerns, mostly around spouses buying presents for each other.

Assume the families are like so:

```
List<List<string>> families = new List<List<string>> () 
{
    new List<string>() { "A1", "A2" }, 
    new List<string>() { "B1", "B2" }, 
    new List<string>() { "C1", "C2" }, 
    new List<string>() { "D1", "D2" }
};
```

People in family A can't buy for the others in their family, likewise for families B, C, D.

We can easily get a family from a given person with:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> FamilyOf(this List<List<string>> families, string person)
{
    return families.Where(family => family.Contains(person)).First();
}
```

... and we can get all valid pairs with:

```
var everyone = families.SelectMany(family => family);
var pairs = from giver in everyone
            from receiver in everyone
            where !families.FamilyOf(giver).Contains(receiver)
            select Tuple.Create(giver, receiver);
```

How can I turn this into the possible collections of permutations of valid givers/receivers that includes everyone? From that I'll just select a random collection.

Comment: I would consider modeling this as a graph problem. The people are nodes in a directed graph. Arrows are the "can buy for" relation. Construct the k-complete graph for all nodes, and then remove the edges that represent "illegal" pairs. Now for each node in the graph, choose an outbound arrow; when you do, eliminate all the other outbound arrows from the original node, and all the inbound arrows from the chosen node. A configuration in which there are nodes pointed to by no one or pointing to no one is illegal; reject it.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a bit of code to solve your problem, but it can sometimes throw an exception, when it gets a bit "unlucky" with picking the pairs. For example if the algorithm pairs A1B2 B1C2 C1A2 -> so only D1 and D2 are left, which causes an exception since it doesn't meet your pairing requirement anymore.

Anyway here is the code, which you might want to expand to prevent it from throwing an exception:

```
        var everyone = families.SelectMany(family => family).ToList();
        everyone.Shuffle();
        var randPairs = families.SelectMany(family => family)
            .Select(p => new { 
                Giver = p, 
                Receiver = everyone.PopRandom(x => !p.Contains(x[0])) 
            });
```

And the two extension methods for IList:

```
    public static T PopRandom<T>(this IList<T> list, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        var predicatedList = list.Where(x => predicate(x));
        int count = predicatedList.Count();
        if (count == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        T item = predicatedList.ElementAt(Rand.Next(count));
        while (item != null && !predicate(item))
        {
            item = predicatedList.ElementAt(Rand.Next(list.Count));
        }
        list.Remove(item);

        return item;
    }

    public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        int n = list.Count;
        while (n > 1)
        {
            n--;
            int k = Rand.Next(n + 1);
            T value = list[k];
            list[k] = list[n];
            list[n] = value;
        }
    }
```